# Template data not passing into Django view.py

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

[image]

We are trying to get the name, email-ID and password through post method in the form, we get the data as none instead of the data filled in the form.

**view.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
# Create your views here.

def sign_up_in(response):
    email = response.POST.get('eemail')  #Getting the data of email by the name of eemail
    print(email)                         #Trying to print the email that we got from the form
    return render(response, "main/sign_up_in.html",{})
```

**HTML code**

There are two forms and we are trying to get the data from the first form. The first form is for creating the account and the second is for signing in.

```
<form method="POST" class="form" id="a-form" action="">
                    <h2 class="form_title title">Create Account</h2>
                    <div class="form__icons"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data" alt=""><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"></div><span class="form__span">or use email for registration</span>
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="eemail">
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                    <input class="form__input" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <button class="form__button button submit">SIGN UP</button>
                </form>
<form method="POST" class="form" id="b-form" action="">
                    <h2 class="form_title title">Sign in to Website</h2>
                    <div class="form__icons"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data" alt=""><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"></div><span class="form__span">or use your email account</span>
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="eemail">
                    <input class="form__input" type="password" placeholder="Password"><a class="form__link">Forgot your password?</a>
                    <button class="form__button button submit">SIGN IN</button>
                </form>
```

**url.py**

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   path("", views.Home, name = "Homes"), 
   path("sign/", views.sign_up_in, name = "sign_up_in") 
]
```

Comment: Note that your `Email` and `Password` fields both don't have a name specified and your `Name` field has a name set to `eemail`. Is that intentional? Are you aware of that when testing your code?

Comment: Is this form on the page with the url `sign/`? And do you get `None` as the output _before_ or _after_ submitting the form? You are surely going to get that before submitting the form when hitting the page as you print that regardless of the request's method.

Comment: Yes, sign/ is the url of the form. We are printing the data after hitting the submit button the data is shown as NONE.

Comment: @KshitijKarkera do you get two prints as `None` or one? I believe it should be one `None` and other print with your actual input (or an empty string if you don't enter anything, so an empty line)...

Comment: GwynBleidD We only gave the name to the email textfield to test if the request is working or not

Comment: @KshitijKarkera Are you submitting the form via JavaScript? because it seems that you haven't given URL for form action attribute..

Comment: Nanthakumar J J We indeed used javascript, but we didn't knew how to link with django using url sign_up_in.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should do it like this **
*Write request instead of response and check that the method is GET or POST*

```
def sign_up_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('eemail') 
        print(email)                         
    return render(request, "main/sign_up_in.html",{})
```

**Inside HTML**
*Add action where you want to post data using form (use name of the path) ex: for signup*

```
<form method="POST" class="form" id="a-form" action="{% url 'sign_up_in' %}"> #path name
                <h2 class="form_title title">Create Account</h2>
                <div class="form__icons"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data" alt=""><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"></div><span class="form__span">or use email for registration</span>
                <input class="form__input" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="eemail">
                <input class="form__input" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <button class="form__button button submit">SIGN UP</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it didn't showed any output in the terminal after submitting the form

Comment: Hey @KshitijKarkera could you please put those codes in a repository so that I can clone and test them by myself..

Comment: This is the whole project 
file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15XwPuHm755VAJaqQGOrbr8KF1T5Z23bz/view?usp=sharing

We are unable to upload it to the repository, so you can download it from the drive and check the code

Comment: Hey @Nanthankumar J J Did you check my code??

Comment: @KshitijKarkera it is too much large in size.... please share only necessary things
and one more thing bro is that are you using AJAX to post this form because I bet that my code will work 100%...
You can contact me at my linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/mohit-rathore-9299441aa/